# Unexpected end of input with Parsec

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

I try to parse the following text file with series of data between keywords :

```
many text many text  many text 

BEGIN
T   LISTE2
1   154
2   321
3   519
4   520
5   529
6   426
END

many text  many text  many text
```

By using the following haskell program

```
import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.String
import Text.Parsec.Char
import Text.Parsec.Combinator

endOfLine :: Parser String
endOfLine =     try (string "\n") 
            <|> try (string "\r\n") 

line = many $ noneOf "\n"

parseListing = do 
  spaces
  many $ noneOf "\n"
  spaces
  cont <- between (string "BEGIN\n") (string "END\n") $ endBy line endOfLine
  spaces
  many $ noneOf "\n"
  spaces
  eof
  return cont

main :: IO ()
main = do
    file <- readFile ("test_list.txt")
    case parse parseListing "(stdin)" file of
            Left err -> do putStrLn "!!! Error !!!"
                           print err
            Right resu -> do  putStrLn $  concat resu
```

And when I parse my text file, I get the following error :

```
"(stdin)" (line 16, column 1):
unexpected end of input
expecting "\n", "\r\n" or "END\n"
```

I'm a newbie with parsing and I don't understand why it fail?
My sequence is yet between `BEGIN` and `END`

Do you know what is wrong with my parser and how to correct it ?

Comment: Please include the actual code that produced the parse error (and also the string input or text file).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `between` will never stop, because `endBy line endOfLine` consumes any line and `END\n` too, so it will eat more and more lines until it fails.
Then your parser tries to consume `string "END\n"` and fails too, that's why error message mentions `"END\n"`
You must rewrite line parser to fail on `END\n`. For example:

```
parseListing :: Parsec String () [String]
parseListing = do 
    spaces
    many $ noneOf "\n"
    spaces
    cont <- between begin end $ endBy (notFollowedBy end >> line) endOfLine
    spaces
    many $ noneOf "\n"
    spaces
    eof
    return cont
    where
        begin = string "BEGIN\n"
        end = string "END\n"
```